# Why are batch file command line parameters disappearing in the console?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, console, windows-7

I wrote the simplest of simple batch files:

```
for /d /r %%a in (*) do echo "%%a"
pause
```

When I save these 2 commands as a batch file and run that batch file in Windows 7, the output in the console begins with:

```
for / %a in (*) do echo "%a"
```

Why are the `/d /r` parameters for the `for` command not displayed in the console output?

Comment: This seems to be a bug of the `for /D` command…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks.  Out of curiosity, which version(s) of Windows did you test?

Comment: Well, I am not sure when I first noticed it (it might have been on Windows XP), but I have seen it on Windows 7 and on Windows 10…

Comment: `cmd.exe` of version `5.1.2600.5512` installed on Windows XP SP3 has the same `for /D` display bug as `cmd.exe` of version `6.1.7601.17514` installed on Windows 7 SP1 and even newer `cmd.exe` versions installed on newer versions of Windows.